# Related Rates (Pyramid)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This is the question →
[image]

I'm having trouble forming an equation for all of this question.
Also do I have only have to use one chain rule or 2 chain rules to find $\frac{\mathrm{d}SA}{\mathrm{d}t}$, I also know we are given $\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t}$... but the part where the top is cut off and a new flat top is added is very confusing... Could someone please guide me!

Comment: If the "part where the top is cut off and a new flat top is added" is confusing you, what about if it were just a regular pyramid?  All that changes is that instead of water depth of 15cm, we now are curious for water depth of 35cm. (the 15 originally asked for plus the 20 that would have been a result of not cutting off the top)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that the bottom *has not been cut off*. Let $y=y(t)$ be the vertical distance at time $t$ from the bottom tip to the top of the water. Then the area $A=A(t)$ of the top of the water is $y^2$.

Let the volume from the bottom tip to the top of the water be $U=U(t)$. We are told that $U$ is increasing at the rate $3000$, so $\frac{dU}{dt}=3000$.  Note that
$$U=\frac{1}{3}y^3,\tag{1}$$
and therefore 
$$A=y^2=(3U)^{2/3}.\tag{2}$$
Differentiate both sides with respect tp $t$, and finish by calculting $U$ when $y=35$.

**Another way**:  We could use $U=\frac{1}{3}y^3$ to find $\frac{dy}{dt}$ when $y=35$, and then use $\frac{dA}{dt}=2y\frac{dy}{dt}$ to find the rate of change of area at that time.

Comment: Wow thanks! The other method worked well :D

Comment: You are welcome. The first method is somewhat quicker to write the details for, but the differentiation is messier and more likely to lead to error. The second method only involves differenting a square and a cube.

Comment: Also one last question, why did we do y = 35 instead of y = 15? I thought 20 cm is cut off from the pyramid?

Comment: When the water is $15$ cm deep, the distance from the top of the water to the tip of the pyramid is $15+20$. Things are geometrically a little nicer if we imagine the tip has not been cut off, but has water in it to the $20$ cm mark when the hose is turned on. It makes no difference, my $U(t)$ is changing a the same rate as the volume $V(t)$. Also, the height from the bottom of the ex-pyramid is nicer geometrically than the height of the water in the real problem, and is changing at the same rate. You could use the true volume of water $V(t)$, which is $U(t)-(1/3)(20^3)$. (More)

Comment: (More) And you could use the true depth $d(t)$ of the water, but then the top would have area $(d(t)+20)^3$ instead of our $(y(t))^2$. That's just messier, more opportunities to make errors.